# Running Script In Multiple Website and Fetch the Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Background:** I manage a forum, and there is a forum event where people post their information. I need all the data from the forum, so i made a script to get all posts within a page. however there are around 100 of pages, so it will be a pain to do it one by one.

**My Target:** Able to get all posts from all pages in the forum.

**What My script Does:** grabbing the data. below is the script

```
var dates = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="postmessage"]');
var result = "";

for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    result += "> ";
    var post = dates[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    var lines = post.split('<br>');

    for (var l = 0; l < lines.length; l++) {
        var line = lines[l];

        if (line.indexOf("ign") !== -1) result += line.substring(line.indexOf("ign") +4);
        if (line.indexOf("server") !== -1) result += line.substring(line.indexOf("server") +7);
        if (line.indexOf("platform") !== -1) result += line.substring(line.indexOf("platform") +9);
        if (line.indexOf("top 5 countries") !== -1) result += line.substring(line.indexOf("top 5 countries") +16);

        result += "|";
    }

    result += "\n";
}

result;
```

**My question:** How can i automatically run this script and get the result from 100 pages?

Comment: hi, can anyone help me point out why my question is too broad? i also edit and add the script.

Comment: how are you loading the page data into the script ? and navigating between pages ? Your codes seems to work on a single page ..

Comment: javascript can only work on the current page that's loaded. Sounds like you need to work on the server-side code and fetch the usage data from the forum database.

Comment: Thanks both of you, Since i'm not the owner nor the employee of the company, i had no access to the source code or any server-side things. Is there any other way, like using local xammp to load the page, run script, and get the data? or even using desktop apps like C# is ok.

Comment: @Neolitz so let's get this straight, you're trying to scrape user data from someone else's website?

Comment: @ADyson, not exactly, i am a player moderator, which jobs is to look in the forum, collect i formation from the poster, and report it to the owner of the site, i got paid by them to do that, but we never meet physically. So there was an event which makes people reply to the thread and it was around 100 page and each page 10 post. I am in charge of collecting the result and sending it back to them, including filtering, fixing, and adjusting, so it's easier to read for them.

Comment: @Neolitz in that case they should give you the proper tools for the job. You should have read-only access to the database, not trying to scrape HTML and parse it.

Comment: @ADyson, yeah i know, but the problem is their dev team is really bad. since I'm not directly communicating with the dev team, The person in charge of me, can't ask what i want to dev, because he can't explain the reason. That's why I'm searching alternate way to get the data beside asking their dev.

Comment: @Neolitz in that case I hope you're charging them a lot of money for their incompetence :-). Anyway, I don't think Javascript is a good solution here. You probably want to use PHP or C# to write a program that will call all the pages one by one (if the URLs have a pattern, you shouldn't need to hard-code much of it). Then you'll have to find or write a HTML parser and look for patterns in the content, so you can identify the items you want.https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=C%23+HTML+parser might be a place to start. Or DIY using regexes

Comment: @ADyson, so in the end i need to use regex and not using my script. I had make a similar program before myself, i was thinking if there a way to use it using script, since it's easier, hahaha, ok thanks for the guidance. since this didn't have any answer, should i just delete the question?

Comment: no you don't need to delete it if you don't want. people can still read the comments.